# Cannot override/monkey patch a rails method with rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, overloading, monkeypatching

I am trying to override an active resource method like explained in this question : [Remove .xml extension from ActiveResource request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301086/remove-xml-extension-from-activeresource-request) and this one :
[i want to use a REST api, i cannot manage to set active resource to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650393/i-want-to-use-a-rest-api-i-cannot-manage-to-set-active-resource-to-use-it)

To do so i tested :

Creating in the /config/in itializers/ folder of my app a file named active_resource.rb with the following code :

```
class ActiveResource::Base   
  def element_path(id, prefix_options = {},query_options = nil)
  check_prefix_options(prefix_options)
  prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
  "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}/#{URI.parser.escape id.to_s}#{query_string(query_options)}"   
  end 
end
```

Adding the method inside my model. Here is my model code :

```
class Player < ActiveResource::Base
  def element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
    check_prefix_options(prefix_options)

    prefix_options, query_options = split_options(prefix_options) if query_options.nil?
    "#{prefix(prefix_options)}#{collection_name}/#{URI.parser.escape id.to_s}#{query_string(query_options)}"
  end
  self.site = "http://ws.maniaplanet.com/"
  self.user="**********"
  self.password="*********"
end
```

To validate the overriding of my custom code I have tried to use

```
puts  "called this method"
```

or

```
ActionController::Base.logger.info "called this method"
```

It has never worked.

Why can't i override the rails method element path ?

UPDATE

Tried to put active_resource.rb in extra after uncommenting the `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)` line in application.rb. No change

If i put the base.rb file with my class and method in lib/active_resource/ it breaks my app. I cannot launch rails server anymore

Comment: What if you try to require ActiveResource before overriding it. `require "active_resource"`. Will it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override class method, not instance one, so:

```
class Player < ActiveResource::Base

  def self.element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
    #...
  end

end
```

That would be enough, if you going to make requests only from `Player` model.

If you want this behaviour for any model, you should monkey patch `ActiveResource::Base`, again, the class method.

```
# config/initializers/active_resource_patch.rb
class ActiveResource::Base

  def self.element_path(id, prefix_options = {}, query_options = nil)
    #...
  end

end
```

Comment: It works but i was hopping to do it only once, as i'll have multiples model using this API.

Comment: @Sylario, no problem with that, it's just Ruby inheritance (see updated answer) :)

Comment: Thx a lot! the monkey patching finally worked! I just needed self. in front, i guess it has to do with instance/module stuff, so thanks a lot.